# How to make SFML VertexArray Pointers?

Tags: c++, sfml, 2d-games

How do i allocate memory dynamically to an SFML VertexArray?

I have a game containing many sprites and menus with different SFML objects. So its crucial for me to get rid of unnecessary memory usage.

I have tried to do simply:

```
sf::VertexArray *example = new sf::VertexArray;
```

But I can't set positions and texture coords like this:

```
example[0]->position = sf::Vector2f(1,1);
[...]
example[0]->texCoords = sf::Vector2f(1,1);
[...]
```

Is there some way to bypass this problem?

Comment: You're looking for `(*example)[0].position`. But then, what you presented here has nothing to do with memory usage reduction -- if anything, it will increase it.

Comment: I would recommend using a smart pointer for that `auto example = std::make_unique<sf::VertexArray>()`. But even better just put them all in a `std::vector<sf::VertexArray> vertex_arrays;`

Comment: I think this question is a bit unclear, what error are you running into? I can't make heads or tails of it when you say "But I can't set positions and texture coords like this" as I'm not sure _what_ is stopping you from doing it. For example, you have a default constructed VertexArray but did you resize it as needed? If not, then your code you posted is broken... and I'm not sure if that is what's causing you the "cant set position and texture coord" or if you've done it right and there is something else. Is this a compiler error? Exception? Signal? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Quentin Why would it increase it ? i can delete it prematurely... can't I ?.. Anyway, thanks for help(i really forgot about that method tbh)

Comment: @SzokeLori You can, but then again at that point you would no longer have use for it, which a stack allocated `VertexArray` would take care of on it's own if you scoped it's lifetime correctly.